# Масштабирование canvas работает не корректно

Tags: javascript, canvas, графика

Пробуб масштабировать canvas относительно расположения курсора, но он сдвигается постоянно на пару клеток влево/вправо. В чем причина и как исправить?

https://jsfiddle.net/shumikua/3afxtmqw/

```
function scale(svg, e){
        let x = e.originalEvent.offsetX - canvas[0].offsetLeft;
        let y = e.originalEvent.offsetY - canvas[0].offsetTop;
        let deltaY = e.originalEvent.deltaY;
        let scale_now = deltaY < 0 ? 1.5 : 1/1.5; 
        scaleFactor *= scale_now;
        panX = x - (x - panX)*scale_now;
        panY = y - (y - panY)*scale_now;
        
        draw();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Не до конца понятно, о какой проблеме идет речь. У меня какое-то смещение появлялось, при очень быстром скролле. Я добавил setTimeout к обработчику и смещение исчезло

```
let timer = null;
canvas.on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', (e) => {
  if (timer) {
    timer = clearTimeout(timer)
  } else {
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
      test(e)
    }, 0)
  }
});

function test(e) {
  if (e.ctrlKey) {
    scale($(this), e);
  } else if (e.shiftKey) {
    move($(this), -e.originalEvent.deltaY / 5, 0);
  } else {
    move($(this), 0, -e.originalEvent.deltaY / 5);
  }
}
```